# Jacobian matrix rank and dimension of the image 3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let
$p_1,\dots,p_n,q_1,\dots,q_n$ be polynomials in $m<n$ variables and 
$f(z)=\left(\frac{p_1(z)}{q_1(z)},\dots,\frac{p_n(z)}{q_n(z)}\right)$.
By construction, the variety $V$ is the Zariski closure of the set
$$
\{f(z):\ q_1(z)\cdots q_n(z)\ne 0, z\in\mathbb C^m\}
$$
It is clear that $V$ is irreducible and that $\dim V<m$.

Is it true that $\dim V$ is equal to rank of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at generic point?
(I suppose that the statement is correct but I cannot find a reference)

Comment: See the last lines at page 186 of the following:https://books.google.it/books?id=g9DBgD22n_IC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=algebraic+geometry+dimension+of+image+rational+map+rank+Jacobian+matrix&source=bl&ots=XZnQtPF6A_&sig=we-6MLXcFJVB5ZNT4FDG3FvJixk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwA2oVChMIhabJ7baKxgIVSXxyCh2QJABJ#v=onepage&q=algebraic%20geometry%20dimension%20of%20image%20rational%20map%20rank%20Jacobian%20matrix&f=false

Comment: you are welcome.